# Dynamic environment not loading in NestJS ConfigModule

Tags: nestjs, dotenv, nestjs-config

I have a REST API server in Nest Js. I am trying to separate the environment for test and production.

**ENV files are .env.test and .env.production.**

### script:

```json
"start:test": "SET NODE_ENV=test && nest start --watch"
```

### app.module.ts:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: !process.env.NODE_ENV
        ? '.env'
        : `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.MONGODB_URI),
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'client'),
    }),
    UserModule,
    TalentModule,
    ChatModule,
    ObjectTypeModule,
    RoleModule,
    CompanyModule,
  ],
})
```

process.env.NODE_ENV sets environment but it failed to load env file.

[image]

Database connection failed.
I log the process.env.NODE_ENV does sets this environment still dynamic env file not loading.

Is there anything messing?

Comment: maybe your `envFilePath` is wrong. Try `path.resolve('.env')`

Comment: .env and .env.${process.env.NODE_ENV} both the files are at the same place and when I  put the files hardcoded it work but failed to load dynamic file

Answer (score 2):

simply remove `set` from you script.

<s>SET</s> NODE_ENV=test && nest start --watch

```bash
"NODE_ENV=test && nest start --watch"
```

### package.json:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=env && nest start --watch",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=prod && node dist/main",
  },
...
```

### app.module.ts:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: [`.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`],
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

### main.ts:

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
  await app.listen(port);
}
bootstrap();
```

### app.controller.ts:

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    console.log('my env:' + process.env.NODE_ENV)
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

### console:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above solution if it still does not work try:

```
yarn global add cross-env
```

Go to the package.json

```
"start:test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test nest start --watch"
```